# Type mismatch using C with cnpy library

Tags: c, linux, cmake, point-cloud-library, lidar

I am trying to implement https://github.com/bostondiditeam/MV3D/tree/master/src/lidar_data_preprocess/npyConverter . I tried to compile the code with various versions of cnpy but fail each time with mismatch error even though the passed parameters are the same.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you have trouble compiling their stuff, I'd suggest you open a [new issue](https://github.com/bostondiditeam/MV3D/issues) on their github page. Stack Overflow is not a code reviewing platform for third-party projects.